# Why my function returns so big random values when it has a range?

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to get random float values in a range in a pointer but it gives me some very big numbers. I think my error is in the function calling but i'm not sure.

This is the function:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void random_values(float *arr, int N) // "arr" is used like an array to 
                                      //keep random float values

{                                     // "N" is the length of the array
    int i;
    float max_range=1000.00;
    arr=(float *)(malloc(sizeof(float)*N));
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        *(arr+i)=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * max_range;

    }
    free(arr);
}
```

Here I call the function and try to print it out:

```
random_values(arr, length);
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    printf("%.2f\n", *(arr+i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `random_value` function allocates some memory, fills it with random values, then frees it. It never uses the pointer passed into it for anything. It doesn't put the random value where that pointer points, it doesn't copy the random values to the memory pointed to by that pointer, it doesn't return a pointer to the caller, and even if it did -- it freed the block of memory anyway. So there's no way the caller can possibly access the random values.

Let's go through it line by line:

```
void random_values(float *arr, int N) // "arr" is used like an array to 
                                  //keep random float values

{                                     // "N" is the length of the array
    int i;
    float max_range=1000.00;
    arr=(float *)(malloc(sizeof(float)*N));
```

Umm, what? We got passed the array we were supposed to use, but then we replace that value with a pointer to a different array entirely?

```
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        *(arr+i)=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * max_range;

    }
    free(arr);
```

Okay, we store all the random values in a block of memory, but then we `free` the block of memory? What's the point of that?

```
}

random_values(arr, lenght);
    for(i=0;i<lenght;i++)
        printf("%.2f\n", *(arr+i));
```

This code passes `arr` to `random_values`, which ignores it. Then it prints out the contents of `arr`, which likely contain random garbage since nothing ever followed that pointer and put data where it pointed.

Comment: I can't tell without seeing more code. For example, what value did `arr` have when the function was called? Who is supposed to manage the lifetime of the memory that holds the random data? There's no way to tell without seeing things like how the caller of `random_values` initializes `arr`.

Comment: is there a way that i can fix it :)? I'm a just a begginer.

Comment: I'm sure SO contains 1200 duplicates of that question.

Comment: @Ioncojocaru Can you show the rest of the calling code? Is the caller expecting `random_values` to return a pointer to a newly-allocated block holding the random values? Or is the caller supposed to allocate the array and `random_values` is just expected to fill it? There are insufficient comments and insufficient code to determine precisely what `random_values` is supposed to do.

Comment: i've allocated dinamic memory for that arr and i wanted to store the random values in it by calling the function

Comment: So then why does `random_values` call `malloc` if the memory is already allocated by the caller? It sounds like all you need to do is get rid of the calls to `malloc` and `free` inside `random_values` since it's the caller's responsibility to allocate and free the memory. That makes more sense because then you can do something like `float arr[10]; random_value(arr, 10);` and you can't do that if `random_values` allocates memory.

Comment: David, you're right. Thank you very much. That was the error)))!